# how to Split a column into two column on sql

Tags: sql

eg: Email

```
sundar@gmail.com
larry@gmail.com
```

need to be separated as

```
column1    column2
sundar     gmail.com
larry      gmail.com
```

Comment: Which db please? You will probably need something like `CHARINDEX` or `POSITION` but it varies depending on implementation.

Comment: Should also point you at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, which will help you to provide all the necessary information in future.

Answer (score 1):

in case mysql

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING_INDEX('email', '@', 1) AS name, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX('email', '@', -1) AS domain
```

and in case of mssql

```
SELECT 
SPLIT_STRING('email', '@', 1) AS name, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX('email', '@', -1) AS domain
```

this will output like

```
name       domain
sundar     gmail.com
larry      gmail.com
```